# Object Detection of classes with different "states"

Tags: tensorflow, object, object-detection, detection, object-detection-api

Iam trying to train a model with the Object Detection API and iam a newbie. My aim is to detect multiple food objecs. There is maybe something i am doing wrong, so i decided to ask the community. For example i have a class Apple. I trained this class with apples from different "states". With states i mean, an apple can be red, green, sliced in half, etc etc. Do i have to make a class for every different state like apple_green, apple_red, apple_green_sliced or should i sum up all different states in one class?

Answer (score 0):

If you clearly distinguish the states of an apple, then you would need to have three different classes for each state(if you really want to have that state). So you would have class 1 - red apple, class 2 - green apple, class 3 - sliced apple.

If your purpose is only to distinguish apples from oranges for example or from other fruits, you can group all the pictures with red/green/sliced under the group 'apple'.